Wired Headphone not working with Ubuntu 22.04
I have JBL TWS buds and boat wired earphone with 3.5mm jack. When I use JBL TWS they are working perfectly fine. But when I connect wired earphone, they are not working. voice is coming out of laptop speakers and microphone is not detected. But when I switch to windows everything works perfectly fine. How to resolve this? I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS
